# Passing data to ActionCable disconnect method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Is there a way I can pass data to the disconnect method of my client-side ActionCable channel? I need the ID of the current user so that I can turn off their online status indicator. I've tried and read everything I can find on ActionCable, but I don't understand how to pass data to methods other than received.

```
Live.appearance = Live.cable.subscriptions.create('AppearanceChannel', {

  // need to pass the user's ID here:
  disconnected: function(data) {
    var userId = data['appearances'][0];
    var appearanceContainer = $('.user-status-indicator').filter('#' + userId);
    appearanceContainer.remove();
  },

  received: function(data) {
    var userId = data['appearances'][0];
    var appearanceContainer = $('.appearance-label').filter('#' + userId);
    appearanceContainer.append('<div class="user-status-indicator" id="${userId}"></div>');
  }

});
```

Comment: I think my understanding of this is incorrect. Receive is the only method that actually receives data. Maybe I can add an 'action' string to the data object, and through a switch statement I can perform the Jquery required to remove the online status label within received?